# Python: Writing column in CSV with if-statement

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

Using Python, I'd to write a specific text in a CSV file when it is not equal to the value "null". That sounds like I need a if/then statement, but I'm uncertain how to structure it.

The original CSV format is:

[image: CSV1]

I'm seeking to add another column "text_number" that will insert the string "text_x" if the value is not null. I'd like to iterate this and increase the string's value by 1 for each text. The final product would look like:

[image: CSV2]

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: You should open your CSV as a pandas dataframe. It will be very easy to add your new column

Comment: Better to post a sample of the contents of your CSV as text and not as an image. As it is, we cannot tell if the text column contains the string 'null' or is actually empty.

Comment: what did you try ? where is your code? With standard module `csv` it will need a lot of code, with `pandas` `DataFrame` it should  be easy like `df["text_number"][ df["text"] == "Some text0" ] = "text_0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import csv

output = list()
with open("test.csv") as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if i == 0:
            output = [row+["text_number"]]
            continue
        if row[-1]!="null":
            tnum = row[-1].split()[-1]
            output += [row + [f"{tnum[:-1]}_{tnum[-1]}"]]
        else:
            output += [row]
            
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in output:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

`test.csv` used:

```
user_id,text
0,null
1,null
2,null
3,null
4,Some text0
5,Some text1
```

`ouput.csv` generated:

```
user_id,text,text_number
0,null
1,null
2,null
3,null
4,Some text0,text_0
5,Some text1,text_1
```